# How to set response type to id_token in OAuth2 client in springboot application

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

```
security:
 oauth2:
   client:
     clientId: 1213123213131
     clientSecret: 123213213213212313213
     accessTokenUri: https://idp-staging.com/SecureAuth12/OidcToken.aspx
     userAuthorizationUri: https://idp.com/SecureAuth12/SecureAuth.aspx
     tokenName: oauth_token
     response_type: code id_token
     authenticationScheme: query
     clientAuthenticationScheme: form
     useCurrentUri : false                  
     scope:
               - openid
               - profile
     preEstablishedRedirectUri: https://pmx-beta.com
   resource:
     userInfoUri: https://idp-staging.com/SecureAuth12/OidcUserInfo.aspx
```

Generated authenticated URL  set response_type as code instead of code+id_token

Answer (score 2):

I'm still looking for the best way to do that but figured out a workaround.
I've added the custom implementation of **OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver**.

```
public class CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver implements OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver {
    private final OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver delegatedRequestResolver;

    public B2CPolicyResolver( ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository, String authorizeUri ) {
        this.delegatedRequestResolver = new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver( clientRegistrationRepository, authorizeUri );
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2AuthorizationRequest resolve( HttpServletRequest request ) {
        OAuth2AuthorizationRequest req = delegatedRequestResolver.resolve( request );
        return customizeRequest( req, request );
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2AuthorizationRequest resolve( HttpServletRequest request, String clientRegistrationId ) {
        OAuth2AuthorizationRequest req = delegatedRequestResolver.resolve( request, clientRegistrationId );
        return customizeRequest( req, request );
    }

    private OAuth2AuthorizationRequest customizeRequest( OAuth2AuthorizationRequest request, HttpServletRequest httpRequest ) {
        Map< String, Object > params = new HashMap<>( request.getAdditionalParameters() );
        params.put( OAuth2ParameterNames.RESPONSE_TYPE, request.getResponseType().getValue() + " id_token" );
        return OAuth2AuthorizationRequest
                .from( request )
                .additionalParameters( params )
                .build();
    }
}
```

And then configure this class in SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityAutoConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;

    @Override
        protected void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth2/token", "/oauth2/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .oauth2Login()
                    .authorizationEndpoint()
                        .authorizationRequestResolver(
                                new B2CPolicyResolver(
                                        clientRegistrationRepository,
                                        "/oauth2/authorization"
                                )
                        );
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you're close. :)  i wish there was a cleaner way to do this in boot 2.1 using security 5.1

```
private OAuth2AuthorizationRequest customizeRequest( OAuth2AuthorizationRequest request) throws IllegalAccessException {
    final OAuth2AuthorizationRequest newRequest = OAuth2AuthorizationRequest.from(request).build();
    FieldUtils.writeField(newRequest.getResponseType(), "value", "id_token", true);
    return newRequest;
}
```

there's no way to override or extend `responeType` in a `OAuth2AuthorizationRequest`.  replacing `OAuth2AuthorizationRequest` looks a major pain so we have to use a bit of reflection here. `FieldUtils` is part of commons lang 3.